# Are all Darboux functions derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know that the derivative of a differentiable need not be continuous, but it must at least be Darboux, meaning, it satisfies the Intermediate Value Theorem. But that raises the question, is the converse true? That is, is every Darboux function the derivative of some function? If not, can someone give me a counterexample?

Comment: Conway base 13 function.

Comment: There are Darboux functions that are highly discontinuous at any point ( for example they send every interval to the real axis surjectively) but derivatives are Baire class one so can be discontinuous only on meager sets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some pretty simple, otherwise-well-behaved counterexamples.  For instance,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\left|\frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\right|, & x > 0 \\ 0, & x \leq  0\end{cases}$$
is Darboux and continuous everywhere except at $x=0$, but it cannot be a derivative of any function effectively because $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \infty$.

Specifically, suppose $F$ is some function such that $F'=f$ and let $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$.  Then by the mean value theorem, $F(0) \leq F(\varepsilon)$, and by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F(\varepsilon) = F(1) - \int_{\varepsilon}^1 f(x)\,dx$, so by letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, we have
$$F(0) \leq F(1) - \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = -\infty$$